# A Ruby on Rails route error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

But I'm having trouble with a "new user" registration form.

Can someone explain this bug?

I get this error at my signup page:

```
No Method Error

undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x104b06c60>:0x104b018f0>

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <br />
4: 
5: <div>
6:   <%= form_for(@user, :id => 'registration_form') do |f| %> 
7:     <h2>Get started!</h2>
8:     <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
9:     <table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a users route. The error has nothing to do with Mongo - check your routes.rb and ensure that you have the right routes defined.

Answer (score 0):

The users_path method is generated by your routes.rb file. Just make sure you have this in there:

```
resources :users
```